# Why does this use, in Java, of regular expressions throw an "Unclosed character class" exception at runtime?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have list of keywords:

```
String[] keywords = {"xxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz"};
String[] another = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
```

I am trying to identify text that has one of the keywords followed by a space and then followed by one of the "another" words.

if I use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(keywords+"\\s"+another);
```

This throws an exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 57
[Ljava.lang.String;@3dd4ab05\s[Ljava.lang.String;@5527f4f9
                                                         ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suspect you mean `String[] keywords = {...};` and `String[] another = {...};`. If you don't then there's your compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error is correctly telling you that the pattern you're trying to create is invalid.  The gibberish looking string starting with `[Ljava` is the string you passed to `Pattern.compile()`.

Java Arrays unfortunately do not have very informative `.toString()` output, and what you're doing here is essentially concatenating two arrays as Strings, which `Pattern` cannot hope to parse correctly.

But even if you called [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), you'd still not get what you're looking for:

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(Arrays.toString(keywords)+"\\s"+
                                Arrays.toString(another));
System.out.println(pattern.pattern());
```

> ```
> [xxxx, yyyy, zzzz]\s[aaa, bbb, ccc]
> ```

This is a technically valid, but essentially meaningless regular expression, which will only match three-character Strings starting with one character from `xyz ,` followed by one whitespace character, followed by one character from `abc ,`.

I would suggest reading more about how regular expressions work; there's lots of resources online to help, and a good starting point is the [Java Regular Expressions lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and the [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - you won't get very far until you understand what regular expressions are trying to do.

As a starting point however, a regular expression that matches one of several words, followed by a space, followed by one of several other words, might look like this:

```
(?:xxxx|yyyy|zzzz)\s(?:aaa|bbb|ccc)
```

This uses "non-capturing groups" and the logical OR operator `|` to specify multiple potential matches.

Comment: I really appreciate that. It is the grouping of words where I completely blanked out. Thanks for the links! Will sure go through!

Comment: Glad I could help, tweety.  I'd appreciate feedback from whoever downvoted though, I'll be happy to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`[Ljava.lang.String;@3dd4ab05` is the result of calling `toString()` on a string array.

You need to build your pattern manually with the items that are in the relevant arrays.

Comment: I tried doing that. 

Pattern.compile({“xxxx |yyyy |zzzz “ +”\\s”+”aaa|bbb|ccc”};

This produces incorrect results. 

It produces texts with just xxxx or just ccc